When $f \times g$ is such that every point has dense orbit?
For a compact metric space $X$ and functions $f,g: X \rightarrow X$, $f \times g: X^2 \rightarrow X^2$ is defined by $(f \times g) (x,y) = (f(x),g(y))$. We also write $(f\times g)^n(x,y) = (f^n(x),g^n(y))$, where $f^n(x)$ denotes $f\circ f \circ \dots \circ f$ $n$ times.
I'm looking for conditions that imply that $f \times g$ is such that every point has dense orbit, but so far I haven't found anything. I know that it's a little vague what I'm asking, but even then I'm a bit lost on this. Thanks for any help.

Assuming $f,g: X \to X$ are continuous, another way to phrase your question is, when is the (direct) product system $(X \times X, f \times g)$ minimal?
For this to hold you need that $(X,f)$ and $(X,g)$ are minimal to begin with.
I think, then, a necessary and sufficient condition is that for each $x_1,x_2 \in X$ we have that $(x_1, g(x_2)) \in \overline{O_{f\times g}((x_1,x_2))}$, where $\overline{O_{f\times g}((x_1,x_2))} =\overline{ \{ (f \times g)^n(x_1,x_2) : n\in \mathbb{N}_0 \} }$ denotes the orbit closure of $(x_1,x_2)$.
To briefly explain why, note that if this condition is satisfied and $(x_1,x_2) \in X^2$, then $\overline{O_{f\times g}((x_1,g(x_2)))} \subset \overline{O_{f\times g}((x_1,x_2))}$ and inductively, we see that $\overline{O_{f\times g}((x_1,g^n(x_2)))} \subset \overline{O_{f\times g}((x_1,x_2))}$, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. You can use this, and the fact that in a minimal system, the set of visit times of any point in any non-empty open set is syndetic, to show that $\overline{O_{f\times g}((x_1,x_2))}= X \times X$.
For necessity, you can construct counterexamples by playing around with irrational orbits on the torus (e.g. $f(x)=x+\alpha \mod 1$, $g(x)=x+2\alpha \mod 1$, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R\setminus Q}$).
Update with sketch of the last claim in proof sketch: If the claim is not true, there is a point $(x,y)\in X^2$ and open sets $U,V\subset X$ so that $(x,y)\in U\times V$ and $U\times V$ is disjoint from all the orbit closures (under $f\times g$) of $(x_1,g^n(x_2))$ for each $n$. However, because $x_1$ visits $U$ under $f$ we can find $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^k(x_1) \in U$ and then, because $x_2$ visits $V$ syndetically under $g$ we can find $n(k)$ so that $g^{k+n(k)} (x_2) \in V$. Hence, $(f^k(x_1), g^k (g^{n(k)}x_2) ) \in U\times V$, a contradiction.

Can you be a bit more explicit in why the syndetic property is enough? $L$ is syndetic if it exists an $N$ such that $L$ meets every interval of length $N$ of $\mathbb{N}$, but you would need that in fact there's an $N$ such that $g^{kN}(x_2)$ is in $V$ for a nonempty open set $V$ and for every $k$ or something like that is is not? Or why the syndetic property helps?

I hope the update helps.

I still have the question on why an $n(k)$ such that $g^{n(k)+k}(x_2) \in V$ exists. I get that the set of visit times is syndetic but this only means that any segment of length $N$ of natural numbers intersects the set of visit times, but this doesn't directly say that there's a $k$ such that $n(k)+k$ is in the set of visit times. How do we know that $n(k)+k$ isn't outside the set of visit times

Consider the sequence $g^{k+1}(x_2), g^{k+2}(x_2), g^{k+3}(x_2), \ldots$. If an $n(k)$ as above does not exist, then any interval of the form ${k+1,k+2,...,k+N}$ will not intersect the visit times of $x_2$ to $V$ under $g$, which is a contradiction.
